# How I can get specific text from Jenkins Console log to editable email notification

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Below is the console log. From this log, I need only 1 link which is highlighted as bolder.

```
11:23:43.329 [Forwarding newSession on session null to remote] INFO  o.o.s.remote.ProtocolHandshake - Detected dialect: W3C
11:23:43.514 [pool-1-thread-11 for channel id=7] WARN  o.o.s.devtools.CdpVersionFinder - Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 100, so returning the closest version found: 96
11:23:43.515 [pool-1-thread-11 for channel id=7] INFO  o.o.s.devtools.CdpVersionFinder - Found CDP implementation for version 100 of 96
  [32mGiven [0m[32mI am on the login page[0m                                                [90m# com.swtestacademy.springbootselenium.cucumber.steps.LoginSteps.iAmOnTheLoginPage()[0m
  [32mWhen [0m[32mclick on signup button[0m                                                 [90m# com.swtestacademy.springbootselenium.cucumber.steps.LoginSteps.clickOnSignupButton()[0m
  [32mThen [0m[32mI try to login with [0m[32m[1m""[0m[32m and [0m[32m[1m""[0m                                          [90m# com.swtestacademy.springbootselenium.cucumber.steps.LoginSteps.iTryToLoginWithAnd(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)[0m
  [32mThen [0m[32mI verify invalid login message for each field[0m                          [90m# com.swtestacademy.springbootselenium.cucumber.steps.LoginSteps.iVerifyInvalidLoginMessageForEachField()[0m
[32m[1m┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐[0m
[32m[1m│[0m View your Cucumber Report at:                                            [32m[1m│[0m
[32m[1m│[0m [1m[36m[4m**https://reports.cucumber.io/reports/fd3e73cd-dd42-44d3-b601-bc7581e11618**[0m [32m[1m│[0m
[32m[1m│[0m                                                                          [32m[1m│[0m
[32m[1m│[0m This report was published in collection "mooninvoice"                    [32m[1m│[0m
[32m[1m└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘[0m[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 28.978 s - in com.swtestacademy.springbootselenium.cucumber.RunCucumberTest
[INFO] Examples.Example #1  Time elapsed: 26.037 s
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[JENKINS] Recording test results
```

Comment: @Vipin Choudhary Can you please check the above issue

Comment: Hi I am looking to the same in in my jenkins job . any solutions?